# How to read record from DB pass to method and update DB using Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have to read data from Table_1 where flag is 'Y' or 'N' and then pass that data to a method call which will return me some response pass or fail then based on response received I need to update the same record flag with Pass or Fail.
How to read data and then call the method on it and update same record ?
I was doing this thing using tasklet approach where I did not used any reader or writer. I did all logic in singe java file where I fetched data based on criteria and called method by iterating each record one by one and updating using hibernate. But, now that approach is discarded and I have to use Spring batch provided reader writer functionality.
Any help will be appreciated .
Thanks.

Comment: I will be using JdbcCursorItemReader for reading from table and my processor for processing how do I update the data ?